# Intent and delay in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I write android application that send email with SMTP. but when AsyncTask done work, it immediately close statusDialog. i want to statusDialog has 3 sec delay and after that go to another activity. please help me!

```
public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
private Activity sendMailActivity;

public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
    sendMailActivity = activity;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
    statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
    statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    statusDialog.setCancelable(true);
    statusDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
    try {
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
        publishProgress("Processing input....");
        GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                args[4].toString());
        publishProgress("در حال آماده سازی درخواست...");
        androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
        publishProgress("در حال ثبت درخواست...");
        androidEmail.sendEmail();
        publishProgress("درخواست ثبت شد");
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        publishProgress(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
    statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    statusDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: *i want to statusDialog has 3 sec delay* So add a delay. What is the problem?

Comment: i dont now how do this and then send to other activity

Comment: why adding three seconds ? is it really necessary ?

Comment: when send email has succeeded it show the message. after that i want to send automatically to other activity.

Comment: *dont now how do this* do you know how to search? google or something?

Comment: yes but I can't find my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onPostExecute` method add a delay to the dismiss actions:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
       statusDialog.dismiss();
       sendMailActivity.startActivity(new Intent(sendMailActivity, ...));
   }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: it need to implement method and then your code has error in Handler.

Comment: Make sure you import the correct handler (android.os.Handler) and not the log import... and replace "..." with your intended activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
    try {
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
        publishProgress("Processing input....");
        GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                args[4].toString());
        publishProgress("در حال آماده سازی درخواست...");
        androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
        publishProgress("در حال ثبت درخواست...");
        androidEmail.sendEmail();
        publishProgress("درخواست ثبت شد");
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");

Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        publishProgress(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```